# How to provide link to a file using <a href> in perl?

Tags: html, perl, href

I have a **Perl CGI** script which invokes HTML form, takes input, and process it.

I want to upload the resultant file to the same localhost server (apache2) but after processing, it generates the resultant file and stops without displaying anything. The resultant file is in a temporary folder ($dir) located in cgi-bin folder.

I tried using the `<a href>` HTML tag but it is not working.

```
print "Content-Type: text/html";        
print '<a href="http://localhost/cgi-bin/$dir/test.txt" target="_top">Download your file</a>';
```

Is there any other way to use `<a href>` tag in Perl?

Comment: Is the file available through Apache, can you get the file if you manually navigate to the URL?

Comment: @JussiV No, actually the resultant file is a text file so I get the following error: (8)Exec format error: exec failed:

Comment: That error is because of missing shebang (`#!`) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The resultant file is in a temporary folder ($dir) located in cgi-bin folder

Don't do that.

`cgi-bin` should contain only CGI programs.

Your server is almost certainly configured so it will try to execute *anything* there as a CGI program.

Your text file, which contains data, is not a program, and trying to treat it as one will cause errors.

Save the file somewhere *outside* cgi-bin (or don't save it at all and just output it from the CGI program directly to the browser).

Comment: could you please tell me how can I print the output to browser? I tried this: print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n" ; print "\r\n" ;   print header('text/plain'), $output;

Comment: `print $output`